# How do I make a strict sequence of Activities for an Android app?

Tags: android

I have two Activities (A and B). When I quit the app on my device and come back, it starts activity B instead of A. When I press the back button it backs out to the home screen. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "quit the app on my device", press the back button? Also, you should post portions of your manifest so we can know how you declared these activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it posible that the App is running in the Background after you "killing" it.
In this case the context of the App is saved. It is only in standby.

How is it, when you kill the App with the TAskManager and restart it. Will Activity A appear?

__

Eventually the Problem can be solved if you start Activity B with [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29).

Activity A ---> startActivityForResult ---> Activity B

When you finish B with resultOK then the next time Activity A must appear.

Comment: That was part of the problem... after making sure it wasn't running it was still acting kind of strange, so i uninstalled it and it seems to be working fine now. Thanks!